# Some two columns using alias in order by

Tags: sql, vertica

I have this query:

```
select 
    id,
    count(1) as "visits",
    count(distinct visitor_id) as "visitors"
from my_table
where timestamp > '2016-01-14'
group by id
order by "visits", "visitors"
```

It works.

If I change to this

```
select 
    id,
    count(1) as "visits",
    count(distinct visitor_id) as "visitors"
from my_table
where timestamp > '2016-01-14'
group by id
order by (("visits") + ("visitors"))
```

I get

> column "visits" does not exist

If I change to 
 select 
        id,
        count(1) as "visits",
        count(distinct visitor_id) as "visitors"
    from my_table
    where timestamp > '2016-01-14'
    group by id
    order by count(1) + count(distinct visitor_id)

it works again.

Why does it work for example 1 and 3, but not for example 2? Is there any way to order by the sum of two column using their aliases?

The alternatives I could think of:

- Create an outer select and order it, but that would create extra code and I would like to avoid that
- Recalculate the values in the order by statement. But that would make the query more complex and maybe I would lose performance due to recalculating stuff.

PS: This query is a toy-query. The real one is much more complicated. I would like to reuse the value calculated in the select statement in the order by, but all summed up together.

Comment: Try to use everywhere `"` as quote. `select 
    id,
    count(1) as "visits",
    count(distinct visitor_id) as "visitors"
from my_table
where timestamp > '2016-01-14'
group by id
order by "visits" + "visitors"`

Comment: Order of the SQL statement execution...

Comment: could you expand on that, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expression evaluation order is not defined. If your `visits + visitors` expression is evaluated before aliases you will get the error shown here above.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by that? Every search I make returns that the ORDER BY is evaluated after the select. Would you have any more details on why does it happen only when I sum both values?

Comment: @JSBach the error message is clear: `visits column not found` means that the alias was not "translated" to the corresponding select list item when the expression (visits+visitors)was evaluated. Also: if you look in the Vertica SQL Ref Manual > SQL Statement > SELECT > ORDER BY Clause you will find what you can use in the ORDER BY: (1) single select list items (name/alias or ordinal position), (2) arbitrary expression formed from columns that **do not appear** in the SELECT list, (3) CASE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the alias try using the actual column also try change the type to varchar or nvarchar, and by that I mean the following:

```
select 
    id,
    count(1) as "visits",
    count(distinct visitor_id) as "visitors"
from my_table
where timestamp > '2016-01-14'
group by id
order by (CAST(count(1) AS VARCHAR) + CAST(count(distinct visitor_id) AS VARCHAR))
```